# Tap spin handle

Tags: tools, tap

This thread repair kit came with everything but a handle (T-grip) to set the tap into when driving it in. The tap itself is the second one from the left.

[image]

The driver side of the tap seems to be 8 mm square:

[image]

The instructions say nothing about needing a special tool for the tap:

[image]

Which tool can I use to drive this tap? Also, the kit didn't come with cutting oil, which I didn't think would have broken their bank to include. Is it really needed? I am cutting threads in an aluminum engine block.

Comment: If you've never drilled and tapped, it would be wise to learn as much as possible then practice using a piece of aluminum scrap with at least 10mm thickness. A tap handle is the preferred tool, not a socket as you're controlling the initial threading process requiring precision otherwise ruining the initial threads may occur from off angle threading. Aluminum is easier to work with than steel or cast iron. One example of d&t  procedures; https://www.hagerty.com/media/videos/everything-you-need-to-know-about-drilling-and-tapping-holes-diy/. Cutting oil lubes the sharp tap. Regular oil can help.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a handle, but it would surely make it easier and keep it more square to the hole. Use a socket which fits over it and will hold it (I don't know what size that'd be, but you can easily fit one). There are also triple square sockets which come with quite a few socket sets. You might try one of those if you have it. You just need to ensure the tap is perpendicular to the work so as to not cut the hole at an angle. It isn't hard, you just need to pay attention to what you're doing.

As far as cutting oil, it depends on where it's at. If you're not worried about where the cuttings go, use WD40 or even engine oil. If you are worried about it, use grease, as it will not only work as lubricant, it will pick up all of the cuttings as well. Just pack the flutes of the tap with it, then clean them out A LOT (never go more than a full rotation without cleaning out the grease and putting new grease back on).

Comment: The tap has a square drive and sockets are hexagonal. 4 vs 6 points

Comment: The hole is in the block and right under is the upper oil pan. So I do kinda care about the shavings

Comment: @amphibient - Yes the sockets are hexagonal, but you'll find if you just try, one of the sockets will most likely fit surprisingly well. It only has to grip and hold. It doesn't mean it will fit *exactly* right. If a socket doesn't work, a wrench of the right size will ... it's just harder keeping the tap straight doing it that way.